# Update Individuals that are absent 3 consecutive days

Tags: sql, date

Using SQL 2005. I have three tables: Meetings, Contacts and Meeting_Contacts.

The meetings table has these fields: Meeting_ID,Meeting_Name, Date_Start, Location

Contacts has: Contact_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Missed_Three_Days

Meeting_Contacts: Meeting_ID, Contact_ID

I need to update the "Missed_Three_Days" field if the individual missed three consecutive days, excluding weekends.

e.g. If he missed Friday, Monday and Tuesday the "Missed_Three_Days field would be updated on Tuesday.

Here's where I'm at so far... I get stuck on the where statement.

```
 update contacts set missed_three_days = 'Missed 3 Days' 
 where ID not in 

 (select contact_ID from MEETINGS_CONTACTS mc
  Join meetings m
 on m.id = mc.meeting_id
 join contacts c
 on c.id = mc.contact_ID
 where m.date_start  ???)
```

I have a feeling its obvious... but my mind is not pointing in that direction today.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens if there isn't a meeting on one of those days?....shouldn't it be `Missed_three_consecutive_meetings`?

Comment: three days to today, or any three day gap?  if any, is there a fixed start, or do you start from teh first date they attended a meeting?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Lamak, you are correct it should be missed_three_consecutive_meetings, this would also account for holidays when a meeting would not be held. It would be three days to 'today'. If they attend on the fourth day we would set the missed_three_consective_meetings field to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Shooting from the hip you could create a function that test each missed meeting for a missing 2nd, and then 3rd meeting from the same person.  Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MissedThree
(
@pContact_ID int,
@pKeyDate Date
)
RETURNS Bit
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @pReturnValue Bit = 0  /** FALSE UNTIL PROVEN OTHERWISE */

/** DID CONTACT MISS THIS MEETING? */
IF NOT Exists
    (SELECT Meetings.Meeting_ID FROM 
    Meeting_Contacts INNER JOIN Meetings 
    ON Meetings.Meeting_ID = Meeting_Contacts.Meeting_ID
    WHERE Contact_ID = @pContact_ID AND Meetings.Date_Start = @pKeyDate)
BEGIN

    /** CHECK TO SEE IF NEXT WAS ALSO MISSED */

    DECLARE @pMeetingTwo Date       

    SELECT @pMeetingTwo = MAX(Date_Start) 
                FROM Meetings WHERE Date_Start > @pKeyDate;

    IF NOT Exists 
        (SELECT Meetings.Meeting_ID FROM 
        Meeting_Contacts INNER JOIN Meetings 
        ON Meetings.Meeting_ID = Meeting_Contacts.Meeting_ID
        WHERE Contact_ID = @pContact_ID AND Meetings.Date_Start = @pMeetingTwo)
    BEGIN

       /** CHECKT TO SEE IF A THIRD CONSECUTIVE WAS MISSED */         

       DECLARE @pMeetingThree Date

       SELECT @pMeetingThree = MAX(Date_Start) 
                   FROM Meetings WHERE Date_Start > @pMeetingTwo;

       IF NOT Exists 
               (SELECT Meetings.Meeting_ID FROM 
               Meeting_Contacts INNER JOIN Meetings 
               ON Meetings.Meeting_ID = Meeting_Contacts.Meeting_ID
               WHERE Contact_ID = @pContact_ID AND Meetings.Date_Start = @pMeetingThree)
        BEGIN         
           SET @pReturnValue = 1
        END
    END     

END 

RETURN @pReturnValue;

END
```

From there you would simply need to run a query to identify the culprits.

```
SELECT Contact_ID, Start_Date FROM 
    Meeting_Contacts INNER JOIN Meetings 
        ON Meetings.Meeting_ID = Meeting_Contacts.Meeting_ID 
    WHERE dbo.MissedThree(Contact_ID, Start_Date) = 1
```

The nice thing here is that it uses the meeting table to determine the consecutve nature of meetings... not a calendar which can have problems such as weekends, holidays, non workdays etc.

I'm sure I could come up with a more elegant solution that is more efficient but you'd have to pay me in more than SO points :).  Maybe this gets your creative juices flowing at least.  Lots of people try to avoid functions like the plague.

Also, you didn't mention Sql version so be aware that if it isn't 2008 the Date datatype will need to be swapped for DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might meet your needs.

```
   --select contacts who attended less than 3 of the last 3 meetings
    SELECT 
          contacts.contact_id,
          COUNT(meeting_contacts.meeting_id) as AttendedMeetings
    FROM contacts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (     SELECT TOP 3 
               meetings.meeting_id
           FROM meetings
           ORDER BY meetings.date
    ) as Last3Meetings --the last 3 meetings and their attendees, regardless of when the meeting happened
      LEFT OUTER JOIN meeting_contacts
           ON meetings.meeting_id = meeting_contacts.meeting_id
           AND contacts.contact_id = meeting_contacts.contact_id
HAVING COUNT(contacts.meeting_id) < 3
```

Happy Coding!